# How to apply regex to xpath in Selenium/Python?

Tags: python, regex, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I have a very unstructured HTML document and the best way to clean it (text and link - selected on the attached img) would be regex. So, is it somehow possible to apply this regex to Xpath in Selenium?

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?i).*(zobacz|czytaj|przeczytaj).+<a.+a>\B')
```

What works is:

```
//text()[contains(., 'Zobacz także')]/../a
```

but I'm not sure whether it is the optimal solution and requires many conditions.

[image]

Comment: Why got negative flags? What's unclear?

Comment: i have upvoted  its a good question

Comment: It's pretty clear to me. I would grab all the .text loop them and just compare the string to the regex.

Comment: You can't use regex in an XPath but it looks like you can probably do this using XPath. Please post some sample HTML (instead of the screenshot) so that I can test some XPaths and get back to you. Message me after you update the question.

Answer (score 1):

XPATH has a method called matches but this is available from xpath 2.0 only

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-matches

But as of now most browsers including chrome supports XPATH 1.0 only and are planning to deprecate xpath all together.

https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/903

**so you can use only xpath 1.0 standards like 'contains' you cannot use regex**

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/